# C# Round and Convert to units

Tags: c#, math

My function doesn't work as I expect..

```
        static string FormatWeight(double value)
        {
            if (value > 10000000) return (value / 10000000D).ToString("0.#### t");
            if (value > 100000) return (value / 100000D).ToString("0.#### kg");
            if (value > 1000) return (value / 1000D).ToString("0.#### g");
            return value.ToString("0.#### mg");
        }
```

Value given - **Comes from database** - is ***13190.1(KG)*** it does display as mg where it should display as rounded value to tons ***(14.5T)***. How can we fix issue? Hope my question is understandable.

Comment: What is the actual number in `value`?

Comment: When I run this in .net fiddle passing in `13190.1D` as the value I get back `13.1901g`.

Comment: @ScottHunter as I wrote in description value is 13190.1(KG)

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah it does give that number.

Comment: @lance is the number coming from the database always in kilograms?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes it will be always in kilograms.

Comment: Then shouldn't kg be the default case that just returns value.ToString() and all others would require calculation?

Comment: even changing default case to kg still displays as G

Comment: It's not proper way to do it but I've done ```value * 0.001102``` Since one kilogram is equal to 0.001102 tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's base unit is in mg and you receive kg from the database. You need to change your function to have it's base unit as kg.

```
static string FormatWeightKg(double value)
    {
        if (value > 1000) return (value / 1000D).ToString("0.#### t");
        if (value > 1) return value.ToString("0.#### kg");
        if (value >= 0.0001) return (value*1000D).ToString("0.#### g");
        return (value*1000000D).ToString("0.#### mg");
    }
```